# System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: A constraint violation occurred

Tags: c#, active-directory

While trying to create a new AD account and reaching this line of code...

```
userPrincipal.Save();
```

...I get this exception :

> System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: A constraint
>   violation occurred.

When debugging in Visual Studio I see the following under ExtendedErrorMessage:

> "000021C8: AtrErr: DSID-03200BD2, #1:\n\t0: 000021C8: DSID-03200BD2,
>   problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 90290
>   (userPrincipalName)\n"

It seems like some Active Directory constraint is being violated, but the error does not specify which one or why, or at least I cannot figure out from the ExtendedErrorMessage. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the sample values for `userPrincipal`? Show some more previous lines code related to that.

Comment: It's a problem with what you are changing. So you'll have to show us what you changed on the account.

Comment: I got this error when I was trying to update the UserPrincipalName property of the userPrincipal.  Even setting the property to the same value as it was before was enough to trigger the exception.